# Unable to insert in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Need help on my insert code here. I get an error that

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I am quite new to Entity Framework. Hope you guys can help me.

This is the code:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new MHC_CoopEntities();

    InventList product = new InventList
                       {
                           InventCategory = { CategoryID = 2 },
                           ItemName = "Del Monte Fit & Right Pineapple 330ml",
                           UnitQty = 48,
                           UnitPrice = (decimal) 20.85
                       };

    context.AddToInventLists(product);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Stack Trace:
>   at Coop_WebApp._Default.SaveButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Others\Wabby ko\Entity Framework
>   4.0\EF_Soln\Coop_WebApp\Default.aspx.cs:line 37
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Can you post the full exception message + stack trace?

Comment: question is now updated.

Comment: Can you try setting product.CategoryID = 2; ?

Comment: yup! this is the foreign key from the category table.

Comment: product.CategoryID cannot be seen. i guess what I entered in the line InventCategory = { CategoryID = 2 } is the line that you suggested. I don't know if I'm wrong or right. :)

Comment: Humm try this. Get the Category model object and set it into InventCategory.

Comment: It's now working. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I assume product.InventCategory is a property with a type of Category. When you do `InventCategory = { CategoryID = 2 }`, it only set the `CategoryID` attribute. However, it needs the object. That's why you have you get the Category object from the context and use it to set `InventCategory` property. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an `Category` instance with the given `CategoryID` and then attach it to the context. Attaching is necessary, otherwise EF would create a new `Category` object in the database instead of only setting the relatonship to the existing category 2. You should also make sure to dispose the created context properly to release the database connection - for example by wrapping your code into a `using` block:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new MHC_CoopEntities())
    {
        var category = new Category { CategoryID = 2 };
        context.Categories.Attach(category);

        InventList product = new InventList
                   {
                       InventCategory = category,
                       ItemName = "Del Monte Fit & Right Pineapple 330ml",
                       UnitQty = 48,
                       UnitPrice = (decimal) 20.85
                   };

        context.AddToInventLists(product);
        context.SaveChanges();
    } // <- context gets disposed here at the end of the using block
}
```